# Firebase realtime database read and write data protocol with android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android app using the Firebase realtime database. 
As part of the security requirements of the app, I need to know what protocol is used for read and write data.
For example, if I am looking at the Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), what protocol is used for the setValue function?

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Android SDK communicates with its servers through a socket over port 443 (HTTPS). It uses a protocol known as Web Sockets.